# Primefaces dataTable get current row count

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefacs 5.1 dataTable have 13 records.When I need to click nextLink to get current Page count (i.e) In 10 page has 10 records and seconds has 3 records when I press next click to need rowcount is 3 but it will show 13

```
 <script>
    function rowCount()
    {
    var rowCount = PF('activityDataTable').paginator.cfg.rowCount;
    alert(rowCount);
    }
    </script>
    <p:dataTable id="activityDataTable"
    rowIndexVar="currentIndex" widgetVar="activityDataTable" 
    pageLinks="2" rows="10" value="#{stud.mainList}" var="studTo"  paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{Exporters} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
    <p:ajax event="page" update="activityDataTable" global="false"  listener="#{stud.scrollDatachange}" oncomplete="rowCount();"/>
        ......
    </p:dataTable>
```

My doubt ispaginator.cfg.rowCount show all the record.Then what method to get current page row count.

Comment: Load the given data table [lazily](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml). I only stop reading, whenever eagerly loading a data source is demonstrated anywhere else in the world for no reason.

Comment: @Tiny: regardless of using lazy or not, it always returns the total rowcount if I remember correctly. A simple jquery selector will give the actual count of the page

Comment: @Kukeltje : I did not take the question itself into account :) because loading a data source in a page-wise manner is another name of "lazy loading" in this context in which the questioner is violating the rule by eagerly loading the data source for no practical reason.

Comment: I know, I often did the same and sometimes find out lazy or not is irrelevant. Therefore I now always read it fully do answer or comment ;-)